# How to configure Windows/winsock to reply to IGMP v3 queries?

Tags: windows, winsock, multicast, igmp

Working with Winsock2 for collecting ipv4 multicast data by a Windows 10 host. From Wireshark, igmp joins/leaves work well, which start/stop the switch transmission (switch with snooping + integrated querier). The switch's querier sends periodically igmp v3 general queries as expected, but there's no report generated by Windows. So after timeout (260s), the switch stops sending.
The code is similar to examples at [www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com), with igmp join through IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP socket option. Tried with another host and Windows 7: same problem.

[output of wireshark, host is 192.168.100.34](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLaIJ.png)

So the questions:

- Must the ethernet interface be declared with some option to enable automatic query processing by Windows ?
- Maybe the queries are filtered ? (but firewall is disabled...)
- Missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a way to make Windows reply.
To go on, used a workaround by sending periodic IGMP membership reports through RAW packets, resetting switch IGMP timers.